# Audio metering graph visulization

Tags: ios, core-audio

I want to achieve graph visulizer displayed in below image. how can i achive same.

**Is displaying multiple channels peak and average or it using FFT for getting same graph effect ?**

I am not getting what fundamentals of audio processing this is using ?

**Please give me suggestions on how i can achive same.**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1、You should get the audio's original data, like PCM (CAF/WAV)

2、When you have the original data， you can read the data frame by frame.

3、You can make a FFT performance to get the frequency and energy.

4、The frequency and enerty is the right you want.

There is a open-source project name XMMS. You can learn something.

The final effect:

[image]

Comment: can you have any example or link how i can achieve ?

Comment: have you got the original audio data ?

Comment: yes, I have got audio data  static OSStatus OutputRenderCallback(void* inRefCon, AudioUnitRenderActionFlags* ioActionFlags, const AudioTimeStamp* inTimeStamp, UInt32 inBusNumber, UInt32 inNumberFrames, AudioBufferList* ioData)